# Jenkins can't find artifacts

Tags: jenkins, artifacts

I have a jenkins running a job, after which I want it to "archive artifact", which is basically just get some files.

The Job clones a github and when ran, it generates some log files which I need.
The patter is:

```
logfiles/*
```

I added a command to list the directory to make sure the files are there, and indeed they are.

```
+ ls -la logfiles
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 22 23:23 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Apr 22 23:23 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Apr 22 23:23 1461367410777_testuuid_61746144-3A3A-5555-4944-3D5343414C41.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1248 Apr 22 23:23 1461367410777_testuuid_61746144-3A3A-5555-4944-3D5343414C41_shortmsg.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2521 Apr 22 23:23 1461367410777_testuuid_61746144-3A3A-5555-4944-3D5343414C41_stats.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8035 Apr 22 23:23 1461367410777_testuuid_61746144-3A3A-5555-4944-3D5343414C41_trace_msg.log
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "logfiles/*". Configuration error?
ERROR: ‘logfiles/*’ doesn’t match anything, but ‘*’ does. Perhaps that’s what you mean?
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
```

I don't really understand why they are not found.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks!

Comment: If you edit _Files to archive: logfiles/*_ in the job's config with the files existing do you get an error msg "**‘logfiles/*’ doesn’t match anything**" immediately below?

Comment: Yes :( doesn't make sense

Comment: That's strange, indeed. I tried it here (with v1.566 on Windows but that shouldn't matter) and it worked. What if you define: `**/logfiles/*`? Restart Jenkins?

Comment: It's on prod, can't do that today... :(

Comment: I edited my comment while you replied: _... `**/logfiles/*`?_

Comment: Also tried that, and also absolute path... Nothing works...

Comment: Try to add '.log' or '.*'

Comment: Still not working... I may need to note that the scripts are un on a docker container

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem. I had configured the job to do the git clone. But for some reason I also added the cloning on the build steps... once i removed that jenkins started getting the files properly.

I would still like to understand why this would happen...

Thanks to all